# Не отправляет письмо phpmailer с ajax по кнопке

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

Всем привет!

Не могу понять, где ошибка. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Пытаюсь отправить письмо при нажатии кнопки, но выдаёт ошибку, письмо не отправляется. Самого текста ошибки нет, удалось написать в js, чтобы возле кнопки появлялось слово "Ошибка".
Главное, если не указывать `if(isset($_POST['#request']))`, то письмо отправляется, но каждый раз при перезагрузке страницы, а мне такого не надо...
Сильно не ругайте, если где ошибку допустил, по незнанию или невнимательности :) 
Заранее благодарен.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3">
              <div id="app">
                <form method="POST" id="request">
                  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Номер магазина: </label>
                    <select v-model="selectedUser" class="form-control">
                      <option v-for="site in sites" v-bind:value="site">{{site.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Адрес магазина: </label>
                    <span v-if="selectedUser!==null" class="address form-control">{{selectedUser.address}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Заявитель (инициатор заявки)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"><span></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Телефон заявителя</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"><span></span>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button><span></span>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['#request'])){
          require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
          require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

          $mail = new PHPMailer;

          $mail->isSMTP();

          $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
          $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
          $mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com'; // логин от вашей почты
          $mail->Password = 'test'; // пароль от почтового ящика
          $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
          $mail->Port = '465';

          $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
          $mail->setFrom = 'mail@gmail.com'; // адрес почты, с которой идет отправка
          $mail->FromName = 'Александр'; // имя отправителя
          $mail->addAddress('mail@yandex.ru', 'Александр');
          // $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

          $mail->isHTML(true);

          $mail->Subject = 'Тема письма';
          $mail->Body = 'Привет, мир! <p>Это строка <b>HTML кода</b></p>';
          $mail->AltBody = 'Привет, мир! Это альтернативное письмо';
          $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

          if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           } else {
            echo 'ok';
           }
          }
        ?>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    sites:[
                        {name:'203', address:'test'},
                        {name:'452', address:'test'},

                    ],
                    selectedUser: 'Выбери номер магазина',
                    msg: 'test'
                },

            });

            $(function(){
              'use strict';
                $('#request').on('submit', function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var fd  = new FormData (this);
                  $.ajax({
                    url:'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData:false,
                    data:fd,
                    success: function(msg){
                      if(msg == 'ok'){
                        $('#sumbit').next().text('Отправлено!');
                      }else{
                        $('#submit').next().text('Ошибка! ');
                      }
                    }
                  })
                })
            })
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: у вас в `$_POST` нет ключа `#request` потому что такой идентификатор не передаётся в форме. Добавьте и будет вам счастье

Comment: @ArchDemon, Так разве в квадратных скобках и не передаётся ключ `if(isset($_POST['#request']))` Немного не понял ответа, можете подсказать, что куда добавить...